# Excel 2016 Pivot - Filter categories containing specific subcategories

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is there any way in an Excel Pivot Table (2016) to filter categories that contain certain subcategories - and still keep the category totals?

Let's say I have ten categories "Regions", with many subcategories, but only two of the categories have a subcategory "Business Sales".

I now want to filter to see ONLY the categories that have subcategories with "Business Sales", BUT i still want to see ALL the subcategories in those two categories i.e. I can't filter on the subcategory "Business Sales".

Any ideas are very much appreciated :)

Comment: unfortunately there is no easy way for that, closest workaround is to add a new column to your original data where you can use a formula to check whether that subcategory is included in any of the rows of the same category.